# Cross domain error with Trigger.IO app, even with permissions set

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, trigger.io

I am evaluating trigger.IO and wanted to setup a simple test with some of the data from  my web service. I had a simple jquery ajax request that I I simple changed to use the forge api for ajax and when I run the build it always states

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.com/file. Origin content://io.trigger.forge0872041a3f3011e291d722000a9f3c85 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. -- From line 1 of null

No mater what I do I cannot seem to get this simple ajax request to work.

Now when I look in the config it should (from the looks of it) already allow you to do it to any site but I even added the site I was trying to hit and the same thing..

What makes it even stranger is that I tried doing the boilerplate and that worked fine but I'm using almost identical ajax request only when I try and hit my server I get the cross domain issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, For my own app, I add Cross-Domain Origin headers which allow access for 3rd party clients. You might want to take a look at my GIST for Forge/jQuery adapter [here](https://gist.github.com/3846989) or my [open-sourced app](https://github.com/burgalon/boorgle-spine) which uses this.

Did you add * in your config.json under modules->request->permissions? Can you paste your config.json? 

Try deleting your 'development' directory and running forge build again. This sometimes helps.

Comment: Hello,
I have the same issue... config.json snippet is

"request": {
   "permissions": [
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*", 
    "*://*/*"
   ]
  },

on ios it works no problem, on android.. no

Comment: I think the CORS restriction is only in force on Android, not iOS. The trigger.io documentation is vague on this though, I got this from their devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the forge.request module to do cross-domain requests with Trigger.io:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/request.html#modules-request

The permissions in src/config.json apply only to that module - you cannot use normal XMLHttpRequest unless you have enabled CORS on your server.